# Build Tensorflow on Intel Atom

Tags: tensorflow, gcc, x86, bazel

I am trying to build Tensorflow on Intel Atom using Bazel 0.15 version.

I followed the instruction [here](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-optimization-for-tensorflow-installation-guide) for Build TensorFlow from Source with Intel® MKL.

My bazel command for Intel Atom is

bazel build --config=mkl --cxxopt=-D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=0 --copt=-march=atom --copt=-mtune=atom

But it didn't success.

What is wrong with the installation?

I am using Intel® Atom ™ E3940.

The error is

```
~/tensorflow$ bazel build --config=mkl --cxxopt=-D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=0 --copt=-march=atom --copt=-mtune=atom
Starting local Bazel server and connecting to it...
................................
INFO: Analysed 0 targets (2 packages loaded).
INFO: Found 0 targets...
INFO: Elapsed time: 6.529s, Critical Path: 0.04s
INFO: 0 processes.
INFO: Build completed successfully, 1 total action
```

How can I solve the issue?

Comment: I think `bazel` (or maybe just TensorFlow's specific build script) doesn't handle options containing an `=`, like `-march=native`.  I don't know how to solve this.  But see [How to compile Tensorflow with SSE4.2 and AVX instructions?](//stackoverflow.com/q/41293077).  If the stupid thing would just properly use `-march=native`, it would work everywhere (building on an AVX2 host vs. building on an Atom).

Comment: @Chile: This question has no obvious connection to Intel's pre-built Tensorflow.  The tag-usage guideline says it's for Skylake Xeon, but this question was about Atom (not even AVX support).  Even if you think they *should* have been using Intel's tensorflow build, that wasn't what the question was about.  It was about compiling from source.  I re-added the tensorflow tag.  The "intel" tag maybe isn't relevant here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My command is not complete.

The complete command is

```
bazel build --config=mkl --cxxopt=-D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=0 --copt=-march=atom --copt=-mtune=atom //tensorflow/tools/pip_package:build_pip_package
```